# How do I get the details entered by the user to go onto a new line in the text file in python?

Tags: python

'''volunteerList.append([ [name], [coinType], [weight], [correct], "\n"])'''

the piece of code above is the code I have tried but the details entered end up on the same line and delete parts of the last set of details entered.

Comment: Are you writing to a file, or appending to it?

Comment: appending to it.

Comment: you may want to include the code where you are writing to the file

Comment: '''volunteerList.append([ name, coinType, weight, correct, "\n"])
                
                volunteerFile = open("CoinCount.txt","w")
                for item in volunteerList:
                    volunteerFile.write("{},{},{},{}".format(*item))'''

Comment: @Coding101 - You shouldn't open with "w" when appending to an existing file. It renders the file non-readable.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where the file is in this example but you would want to do this not to overwrite a file:

```py
name = "A"
coinType = "B"
weight = 99
correct = False

your_list = [ name, coinType, weight, correct]
text = "\n" + " ".join([str(x) for x in your_list]) 

with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: Happy to help ;) Please accept this as an answer when you come around again.